# Ubuntu Server randomly becoming inaccessible and comes back if I reboot modem

Tags: networking, server, disconnect

My Ubuntu Server is 14.04.03 amd64 with 3.19.0-33-generic kernel, running on an old laptop and connecting internet via wifi.
I have no solution for this issue as I don't know what to do with it. I did my research but my findings was related to Realtek Wifi, my laptop is using Intel. And there's no ethernet cable is attached. One thing I also noticed is that, no it's not in sleep state.
As I was typing this, server became available again without having me to reboot router and here's the result of  `sudo lshw -C network`

```
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: WiFi Link 5100
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 00
       serial: 00:22:fa:27:ea:94
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.19.0-33-generic firmware=8.83.5.1 build 33692 ip=192.168.1.40 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:30 memory:d8100000-d8101fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 02
       serial: 00:1b:24:fa:a0:8e
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:29 ioport:1000(size=256) memory:d5010000-d5010fff memory:d5000000-d500ffff memory:d6100000-d610ffff
```

And it's inaccessible again, what logs should I check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem I was having exactly the same as better described in here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1488953
I solved this issue by upgrading my kernel to 4.1.6. My server is not becoming unreachable anymore.